# Erro "EventHandler with correct signature not found"

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms

Tenho a página principal e ContentPage dentro da pasta Views. Conteúdo é carregado com sucesso.

```
<Tab Title="Entrar In" Icon="enter.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Entrar}" />
</Tab>
```

Dentro deste ContentPage tenho um botão para executar o login

```
<Button Text="Entrar" Clicked="DoLogin" />
```

Método para login

```
public async void DoLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var UserLogin = new UserLogin
            {
                email = emailLogin.Text,
                password = passwordLogin.Text
            };

            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var dataUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserLogin);
                    HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent(dataUser, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Locale", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
                    var requestResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("endereço", requestContent);

                    if (requestResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        ....
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Desculpe, houve uma falha na sua requisição.", "OK");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Desculpe, houve uma falha na sua requisição.", "OK");
            }
        }
```

A falha (com certeza estou deixando passar alguma "link" por está iniciando nesta linguagem) ocorre pois o método Login está dentro da classe User que encontra-se dentro da pasta Models.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Apresente o seu método login

Comment: Antes de mover o método de login para a pasta Models / classe User, eu conseguia fazer o login.

Comment: Você só moveu ou moveu e corrigiu os `namespaces`? Pelo código apresentado agora, você deveria estar recebendo uma mensagem de erro diferente...

Comment: Adicionei using MyAPP.Models e using MyAPP.Views dentro de AppShell.xaml.cs e xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAPP.Views" dentro de AppShell.xaml. Não adicionei referência para MyAPP.Models dentro de AppShell.xaml.

Comment: E como o botão com o evento `DoLogin()` vai saber que ele precisa fazer esse bind buscando o método na `class User` ?

Comment: Este é o ponto, tentei fazer este bind usando ICommand e não funcionou também.. estou pesquisando mas ainda não achei como fazer.

Comment: Está um pouco confuso e amplo, eu acho que você vai ter rever a sua estrutura. Aliás o `DoLogin()` não deveria estar na `Services` ao invés da `Models`?

Comment: Se eu voltar e colocar a estrutura toda dentro da mesma xaml funciona, mas gostaria de seguir as boas normas e também aprender. Realmente vou migrar para dentro de Services e já.. farei isto já já e te falo se funcionou ou não.

Comment: Criei uma View com os métodos e fiz um Bind do contextpage, <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:UserViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>. Mas o Bind dos campos de login e senha para registro dá o erro: [0:] Binding: 'EmailLogin' property not found on 'MyAPP.ViewModels.UserViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text'  . Dentro do Entry eu usei Text="{Binding PasswordLogin}" e na userViewModel.cs public string EmailLogin { get; }

Comment: Detalhes, tive que criar public ICommand DoLogin {get;} e quando Clico o botão para enviar executo DoLogin = new Command(Login). O método para login é o  public async void Login(object parameter)

Comment: Resolvido então? Seria legal postar a resposta mostrando como você fez para que possa auxiliar outros usuários no futuro.

Comment: Vou atualizar sim. mas falta resolver o problema do Binding dos campos de login e senha.. Hoje vou analisar e atualizar o post..

Answer (score 0):

Para executar o método de login usei o Command dando um Binding no botão.

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoLogin}"/>
```

Dentro do ViewModel usei o ICommand e chamei o método Login

```
public ICommand DoLogin { private set; get; }  

public UserViewModel()
{
   DoLogin = new Command(Login);
}
```